# Is it legal to sell foreign packaged food products without any English on the label?

Tags: england-and-wales, is-x-legal, food, import, labelling

A shop in London sells egg custard pudding mix that appears to be labelled exclusively in Turkish. Is this legal?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The lack of information in English is not the only violation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [No](https://www.merton.gov.uk/business-and-consumers/food-safety/food-labelling#:%7E:text=All%20labels%20for%20prepacked%20food,is%20an%20internationally%20recognised%20brand.)

Food labels must be in English.

Comment: or at least have an english label stickered on.